# Missing files (basic sty files) when TEXINPUTS is set

Tags: pdftex, texinputs

Below is my files tree:

```
.../Doc/Tex/book.tex
.../Doc/Tex/images/im.jpg
.../Doc/TexBase/myTemplate.sty
.../Doc/TexBase/baseImages/logo.jpg
```

On Windows it was enough to set TEXINPUTS evironment variable with some paths and then I was able to compile with:

```
pdflatex Tex/book.tex
```

my document **book.tex** which uses package **myTemplate.sty**
And now im trying to do teh same on Ubuntu 18.04.
When i move all things to one folder (book.tex and myTemplate.sty and folder with images) then compilation is succesfull. But i would like to keep my foder structure as it is more clearly. So i tried to export TEXINPUTS:

```
export TEXTINPUTS=.:./TexBase/
```

but my compilation fail because of unfound many sty-files wchich are part of **texlive-latex-extra** that i already installed. When i UNSET this variable - it compiles ok.
So my question is:
Am i correctly set TEXINPUTS variable? Maybe i should add some other paths? What is the path to those "latex basic STY files"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set

```
export TEXTINPUTS=.:./TexBase/
```

you tell TeX to search here and `./TeXBase` *only*. Other than rather restricted circumstances, you want to allow search of the standard tree too, which is done by have a trailing `:` (to indicate 'then the standard path'). You also probably want subdirectory searching in `./TeXbase`, so I'd use

```
export TEXTINPUTS=.:./TexBase//:
```